(Online) Multiple Testing with very low expected H1 proportion (very few discoveries)
It appears that most (online) FDR tests lose (almost all) of their power, as the non-null proportion of hypotheses tends to 0. Does controlling the FDR even make sense in those cases? Are there any cures? I'm familiar with the weight decay, but in a way, it represents only a workaround by allowing the method to have an inflated FDR for the sake of more statistical power.

You need to control something like the FDR in order to have a good probability that a significance is actually meaningful. Looking for a needle in a haystack is just a difficult problem. If the non-nulls really stand out, i.e., are far away from the null, you may well still have a good chance of finding them. If they don't, it is genuinely hard to find them, which is expressed by the bad FDR you'd need.
